# How to run JMeter with different post requests

Tags: http, jmeter

i want to put my web application to stress test. I can do it with "Http Request Sampler" but we want our post data have different values which can be read from a DB or a file.

How can i accomplish working with different data?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

To do this, use:

- [CSV Data Set](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config), this will export as variables the columns in each row of your CSV
- Then you just use variables this way ${var1} in Http Request sampler